# How to code a multiple timeframe strategy in TradingView with pine-script?

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to code and implement a strategy based on multiple timeframes. The logic is simple as follows -

> Condition 1 = Stochastic K & D both Oversold (or Overbought) on both
> 15 Minutes and 30 Minutes timeframes Condition 2 = K > D (or K < D)
>
> Enter Long (or Enter Short)

How can I code this in TradingView with pine script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [security()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html) function for this purpose.

The following code will request `SMA9` from the daily timeframe.

```
//@version=4
study(title="High Time Frame MA", overlay=true)
src = close, len = 9
out = sma(src, len)
out1 = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', out)
plot(out1)
```

Comment: So in pine-script version 5, I need to repeat the following line  - 

out1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '15m', out)
out2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, '30m', out)

Comment: Yes but do it for the Stoch K & D.